# Naming variable in R from a text File

Tags: java, r, configuration, config

I am very new to R and am looking for a possible solution for this problem.

Suppose I have a variables.txt file (or any other file for that matter), which contains a list of variable names. EX, Product,
                                       Ingredient,
                                       Label,
                                       Manufacturer,
                                       Marketing,

This text file is generated in java and this file has to be read in R and variable are to be named according to the names in the file.

My example code is :
   `list(Product=0,Ingredient=0,Label=0,Manufacturer=0,Marketing=0)`

which is now manually hard coded.

I need a way to get these names of variables from the variables.txt file and dynamically assign them in R. How can this be done?? is there any config file concept in R so that can also be a way out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use:
`data = read.table("file.txt",header=TRUE, sep=".")` ?

The `sep` is depends on the seperator in the file. It could be comma, tab, space, dot or whatever.

With `header=TRUE` that means you want to take the original variable name from the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the list structure described above you can use any read.table or read.csv command to get the names into R as mthbnd showed above.

Say your `file.txt` looks like: `Product,Ingredient,Label,Manufacturer,Marketing`
Read in the file and create a list from it. The Elements will then be filled with `logical(0)`. Then you can easily set all elements to a `0` by using `[ ]` in order to keep the list structure

```
vars <- as.list(read.csv(file = "file.txt", header = T))
vars[] <- 0
```